# How can I eject my external Time Machine hard disk attached to a MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, external-disk, eject

I used the external hard disk with Time Machine for the first time. After that when I tried to eject the disk, I got a message saying that it can't be ejected because it is being used by some processes. I downloaded an app called "What's keeping me?" which tells what processes are using some disk or file. I got these results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Is "/Volumes/ammar" an external disk?

Comment: @klanomath Yes. It's the external disk that I am using with Time Machine

Comment: What if I shutdown the computer? Will this cause problems?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problems